# Reference types with value semantics and equality operator

Tags: c#

[Link:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx)

> • Consider overriding Equals on a reference type if the semantics of
>   the type are based on the fact that the type represents some value(s).
>
> • Most reference types must not overload the equality operator, even
>   if they override Equals. However, if you are implementing a reference
>   type that is intended to have value semantics, such as a complex
>   number type, you must override the equality operator.

a) To my understanding, for different instances of a reference type to be interchangeable, we should override both `Equals` method and the `equality operator` and also make the type *immutable*?

b) Doesn't a *reference type* having value semantics suggest that different instances ( that represent the same value ) of that type should be interchangeable?

c) But according to above quote, certain *reference types* with value semantics should only have `Equals` method overridden, but not also the `equality operator`. How can we claim such types have value semantics, since instances of that type are obviously not interchangeable?

d) So based on what criteria do we decide whether a *reference type* with value semantics should only have its `Equals` method overridden or also its `equality operator`? Simply based on whether or not we're willing to make the type immutable?

thanx

Comment: Did you try here ? :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Regarding point A, yes, the type ought to be immutable. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx):

> You should not override Equals on a mutable reference type.

I think that D is the core question here, and the [framework design guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx) seem to indicate that this comes down to performance:

> AVOID overloading equality operators on reference types if the
>   implementation would be significantly slower than that of reference
>   equality.

Eric Lippert has some interesting things to say about this [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/09/double-your-dispatch-double-your-fun.aspx). My favorite quote from it is:

> The long answer is that the whole thing is weird and neither works the
>   way it ideally ought to.

Personally this lets me breathe a sigh of relief, as I have always been of the opinion that "==" is functionally a readable shorthand for Equals() (even though I know it isn't).

Comment: Note that there can be occasional times where you want to perform a comparison of the values of a mutable reference type.  To address those issues you can use an `IEqualityComparer` for that type with value semantics, if it's appropriate to use that in a particular context.

Comment: so how often we need different values ( and thus need to replace one value object with another ) plays no importance in the decision, even if object creation is expensive? Similarly, does it perhaps also depend on the design technique we're using ( such as Domain Driven Design )?